# Iterate Multiselect Form Element in jQuery, Change Individual Attributes

Tags: jquery, html, iteration, multi-select

I thought this would be more straightforward than it's proving to be. I'm adding many screenshots here for clarification. I have a multiselect HTML form control:

[image]

If I select a tag and click the "Add Tags button," the tag value moves from the multiselect element to the space above it and that moved value gets a specific ID in a hidden form input:

[image]
[image]

For individual elements, this works fine. However, as this is a multiselect box, I should be able to select multiple options in the multiselect and iterate over each to give me distinct IDs. However, when I try to do that using jQuery's each function, I end up with form elements with the same ID:

[image]

How can I get these hidden form eleemnts to have different IDs? Here is my **HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group tagdiv">
<label id="tagslab" for="tags"><label for="tags">Tags</label></label>
<select class="form-control" id="tags" multiple="" name="tags">
    <option value="Tag1">Tag1</option>
    <option value="Tag2">Tag2</option>
    <option value="Tag3">Tag3</option>
    <option value="Tag4">Tag4</option>
    </select>
<span class="addauth" id="addtags">
    <button id="btn-addtag" type="button" value="Add Tags">Add Tags</button>
</span>
<input type="hidden" id="tagscount" name="tagscount" value="">
</div>
```

And here is the **jQuery** function associated with clicking the "Add Tags" button:

```
$(document).on('click','button#btn-addtag',function(){
    var tagcounter = $('.tagsel').length;
    $("select#tags > option:selected").each(function(){
        var itemtxt = $(this).val();
        var itemnum = tagcounter + 1;
        $('<div class="tagsel form-control" id="tagdisplay' + itemnum +'" value="'+ itemtxt +'"><span class="deletetag"><strong>x</strong></span><span class="tagval"> ' + itemtxt + '</span></div>').insertAfter($("#tagslab"));
        $('<input type="hidden" id=newtag' + itemnum +' name="newtag' + itemnum +'" value="'+ itemtxt +'">').insertAfter($("#tagscount"));
        $(this).remove();
    });
    var newcounter = $('.tagsel').length;
    $('#tagscount').attr('value', newcounter);
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide here.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to actually iterate using `++` instead of adding 1 to the item index while `.each()` was iterating. I simply moved the addition of 1 to the index on click. Here's the fix:

```
$(document).on('click','button#btn-addtag',function(){
    var tagcounter = ($('.tagsel').length + 1);
    $("select#tags > option:selected").each(function(){
        var itemtxt = $(this).val();
        var itemnum = tagcounter++;
        $('<div class="tagsel form-control" id="tagdisplay' + itemnum +'" value="'+ itemtxt +'"><span class="deletetag"><strong>x</strong></span><span class="tagval"> ' + itemtxt + '</span></div>').insertAfter($("#tagslab"));
        $('<input type="hidden" id=newtag' + itemnum +' name="newtag' + itemnum +'" value="'+ itemtxt +'">').insertAfter($("#tagscount"));
        $(this).remove();
    });
    var newcounter = $('.tagsel').length;
    $('#tagscount').attr('value', newcounter);
});
```

And the result:

[image]